# Vue router permission based on User Role from Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have Django and Vue project and I need to add permissions in the Vue router based on user role.
I managed to do this in the template by accessing the user data from my user API.

```
<li class="nav-item active mx-1 mb-1">
        <router-link
            v-if="user_data.role != 2"
            :to="{ name: 'activities' }"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
            >Activities
        </router-link>
    </li>
<script>
import { apiService } from "@/common/api.service.js";
export default {
    name: "NavbarComponent",
    data() {
        return {
            user_data: {},
        }
    },
     methods: {
        setRequestUser() {
            this.requestUser = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
        },
        getUserData() {
        // get the details of a question instance from the REST API and call setPageTitle
        let endpoint = `/api/user/`;
        apiService(endpoint)
            .then(data => {
                this.user_data = data;
            })
        },
     },
    computed: {
        isQuestionAuthor() {
            return this.requestUser === 'admin_user';
        },
        isUser() {
            return this.requestUser;
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.setRequestUser()
        this.getUserData()
    }
};
</script>
```

The user doesn't see the button but can still access the pages if enter the path directly in URL.
I can't find a workaround to get the same user data from user API and use it to manage route permissions based on user.role
My router.js looks like this:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/activities",
    name: "activities",
    component: Activities
  },
  {
    path: "/add-activity/:slug?",
    name: "activity-editor",
    component: ActivityEditor,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/activities/:slug",
    name: "activity",
    component: Activity,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/cto-entries",
    name: "cto-entries",
    component: CTOEntries,
  },
  {
    path: "/add-cto-entry/:slug?",
    name: "cto-editor",
    component: CTOeditor,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/question/:slug",
    name: "question",
    component: Question,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/ask/:slug?",
    name: "question-editor",
    component: QuestionEditor,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/answer/:id",
    name: "answer-editor",
    component: AnswerEditor,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    name: "page-not-found",
    component: NotFound
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  //base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Is there any way to do this in vue router or there is a better way?
I am new to Vue.js, please help :)

Comment: You should check out Vue router "Navigation Guards"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by using beforeEnter and fetching user role from API...

```
import { apiService } from "@/common/api.service.js";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/activities",
    name: "activities",
    component: Activities,

    beforeEnter(to,from,next) {
      var user_data = {};
      let endpoint = `/api/user/`;
      apiService(endpoint)
          .then(data => {
              user_data = data;
              if(user_data.role!=2){
                next();
              } else {
                next("/");
              }
          });
    },

  },
```